# Integrating with longitudinal strips to find the surface area of a shell

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, spheres, solid-geometry

Consider a thin spherical shell. Lets look at 1 small element of the shell, which is like a **longitude** of the shell, and let it subtend an angle of $d\theta$ at the centre of the shell.

It has a surface area $dA=2\pi$r*rd$\theta$.

So we can consider many such small elements, each like a longitude of the shell, and each passing through the same 2 poles of the sphere.

Thus we can integrate this expression for surface area, taking limits as 0 to $\pi$, and this will cover the entire area of the sphere. So,

$$A=2\pi r^2\int_0^\pi\,d\theta$$

i.e. $A=2\pi^2$r$^2$

Where have I gone wrong?

Here in the image, the **green** part represents one element, not red.

[image]

Comment: $2 \pi r \  r \ d\theta$ is not surface area element of a sphere. How do you plan to combine such rings of constant radius and width $r \ d\theta$ to make a spherical surface?

Comment: Warm welcome to stackexchange!

Comment: @MathLover these rings are longitudinal, and hence we can combine them

Comment: @nagarkaradi The question is more difficult than I initially thought, I suggest you add a picture so future answers can get up the set up from a glance

Comment: No that is not true. You cannot combine them. If you take any ring of width $d\theta$, you are suggesting theur width is constant throughout the ring. But rhe wudth should reduce as you get closer to the poles. Think of lemon slices.

Comment: @MathLover, but I have taken each ring to have constant width. when we take limit as  tends to 0, this should work right? If not, why not?

Comment: How familiar are with spherical coordinates and how first polar and second polar angles work? We can continue this in chat if required.

Comment: The error is in your computation of the area of the longitudinal strips. You treat them as cylindrical bands, which they are not. That is, you assume that the difference between the area of such a cylindrical strip and the strip in question is an infinitesimal of higher order than $dA,$ and thus can be neglected. But this is an unjustified assumption.

Comment: @Allawonder then why is this assumption valid when integrating on latitudinal strips?

Comment: @nagarkaradi Because then the infinitesimal bands are sufficiently close to being cylindrical.

Comment: @MathLover yes sure

Answer (score 1):

Consider the violet element of area in your picture, comprised between $\theta$, $\theta+d\theta$ in longitude, and between $\phi$, $\phi+d\phi$ in latitude. Its area is
$$
dA'=r\cos\phi\,d\theta\cdot r\,d\phi.
$$
Integrate this on $\phi$ for $-\pi/2\le\phi\le\pi/2$ to get the area of the whole slice as $dA=2r^2\,d\theta$.

Integrating again on $\theta$ for $0\le\theta\le2\pi$ one gets the area of the sphere.